# Meaning of "AB"

Tags: meaning

I'm currently watching [Truth be told](https://tv.apple.com/us/show/truth-be-told/umc.cmc.6hegr60w8pjyfcblgocjek7oo)

in the second episode there are two sentences that mention "AB".

> - I think he's innocent.
> - So what? He's AB, Poppy.

then a second time

> - Cave is housed in San Quentin, right?
> - Yeah
> - So he's AB.

What does AB exactly means?

Comment: Would *Aryan Brotherhood* make sense in the broader context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aryian brotherhood. Aka white boys

Answer (score 1):

It’s ***A**ryan **B**rotherhood*, Poppy’s husband says the term in episode 3.